# What does 'all of ... the people in it irritants' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across a sentence:

> I woke up weary and all of the routines of life were chores, the people in it irritants.  *([Source](http://www.pressreader.com/australia/readers-digest-asia-pacific/20160301/281659664077840))*

In the sentence, I don't understand the phrase "the people in it irritants". Please explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please link the source, there might be some context around the sentence.

Comment: The sentence is taken from a story in Reader's digest, March-2016. Some context:I wasn't feeling any sense of gratitude for my comfortable home or lovely family.

Answer (score 4):

It means "all of the routines of life were chores, and the people in life were irritants." Irritants are things that are irritating. The sentence is using a parallel structure so that the verb 'were' from the previous phrase is implicitly copied into the next phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The writer is communicating that life isn't satisfying and he dislikes dealing with the tasks and people in that life. Think more annoyance then hate.